# CUDA: Is there a way to force each line to complete before moving on?

Tags: c++, cuda

I am new to parallel programming and I appreciate your help in understand how it works. This is a contrived example, where I want the result of an operation to be 50 in every cell of the matrix.

The result depends on a value in an array at [index+1]. This doesn't work so well in parallel programming, as values aren't computed in order, and I get incorrect results every few cells. The band aid I have is splitting the function into multiple ones, but I think there should be a better solution, though I'm not exactly sure what to search for. Thank you.

CUDA code:

```
#include "cuda_runtime.h"
#include "device_launch_parameters.h"
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdint.h>

#include <iostream>

#define TILE_WIDTH 16

using namespace std;

__global__ void cuda_arithmetic(int height, int width, float *B, float *C, float *initial_array, float *result_array){

    int             w                   =   blockIdx.x * blockDim.x + threadIdx.x; // Col // width
    int             h                   =   blockIdx.y * blockDim.y + threadIdx.y; // Row // height
    int             index               =   h * width + w;

    if ((w < width) && h < (height))                    //initial=20, B=2, C=10, result = 17;
        initial_array[index] = powf(C[index],2);

    if ((w < (width-1)) && h < (height))
        result_array[index] = initial_array[index+1] / B[index];
}

__global__ void cuda_arithmetic_step_1(int height, int width, float *B, float *C, float *initial_array, float *result_array){

    int             w                   =   blockIdx.x * blockDim.x + threadIdx.x; // Col // width
    int             h                   =   blockIdx.y * blockDim.y + threadIdx.y; // Row // height
    int             index               =   h * width + w;

    if ((w < width) && h < (height))
        initial_array[index] = powf(C[index],2);
}

__global__ void cuda_arithmetic_step_2(int height, int width, float *B, float *C, float *initial_array, float *result_array){

    int             w                   =   blockIdx.x * blockDim.x + threadIdx.x; // Col // width
    int             h                   =   blockIdx.y * blockDim.y + threadIdx.y; // Row // height
    int             index               =   h * width + w;

    if ((w < (width-1)) && h < (height))
        result_array[index] = initial_array[index+1] / B[index];
}

int main(){

    int             height              =   800;
    int             width               =   8192;

    float           *A                  =   new float[height * width];
    float           *B                  =   new float[height * width];
    float           *C                  =   new float[height * width];
    float           *result             =   new float[height * width];

    for (int i = 0; i < height; i++){
        for (int j = 0; j < width; j++){
            A[i*width+j] = 20;
            B[i*width+j] = 2;
            C[i*width+j] = 10;
            result[i*width+j] = 17;
        }
    }

    float           *gpu_A;
    float           *gpu_B;
    float           *gpu_C;
    float           *gpu_result;

    cudaMalloc((void **)&gpu_A,         (height * width * sizeof(float)));
    cudaMalloc((void **)&gpu_B,         (height * width * sizeof(float)));
    cudaMalloc((void **)&gpu_C,         (height * width * sizeof(float)));
    cudaMalloc((void **)&gpu_result,    (height * width * sizeof(float)));

    cudaMemcpy(gpu_A,       A,          (height * width * sizeof(float)), cudaMemcpyHostToDevice);
    cudaMemcpy(gpu_B,       B,          (height * width * sizeof(float)), cudaMemcpyHostToDevice); 
    cudaMemcpy(gpu_C,       C,          (height * width * sizeof(float)), cudaMemcpyHostToDevice); 
    cudaMemcpy(gpu_result,  result,     (height * width * sizeof(float)), cudaMemcpyHostToDevice);

    dim3            dimGrid((width - 1) / TILE_WIDTH + 1, (height - 1)/TILE_WIDTH + 1, 1);
    dim3            dimBlock(TILE_WIDTH, TILE_WIDTH, 1);

    // CODE OPTION

    // incorrect result
    cuda_arithmetic<<<dimGrid,dimBlock>>>(height, width, gpu_B, gpu_C, gpu_A, gpu_result);

    // correct result
    //cuda_arithmetic_step_1<<<dimGrid,dimBlock>>>(height, width, gpu_B, gpu_C, gpu_A, gpu_result);
    //cuda_arithmetic_step_2<<<dimGrid,dimBlock>>>(height, width, gpu_B, gpu_C, gpu_A, gpu_result);

    cudaMemcpy(result, gpu_result, (height * width * sizeof(float)), cudaMemcpyDeviceToHost);

    for (int i = 0; i < height; i++){
        for (int j = 0; j < (width-1); j++){
            if (abs((result[i*(width-1)+j] - 50)) > 0.001){
                cout << "error: ";
                cout << i << " * " << width-1 << " + " << j << ": " << result[i*(width-1)+j] << endl;
                system("pause");
            }
        }
        cout << endl;
    }
    cout << endl;

    cudaFree(gpu_A);
    cudaFree(gpu_B);
    cudaFree(gpu_C);
    cudaFree(gpu_result);

    delete[] A;
    delete[] B;
    delete[] C;
    delete[] result;

    system("pause");
}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Since your example is contrived, my answer will be somewhat general.

In general, you're dealing with the problem of global synchronization.

1. As you've discovered, the only clean global synchronization point is the kernel launch, so breaking your code into pieces before and after the necessary synchronization point will insert a global synchronization, due to the kernel launch(es).
2. Another approach is to consider whether the necessary synchronization can be *localized*.  If so, you can look at arranging your algorithm/data so that the necessary synchronization can be handled within a threadblock (where shared memory and `__syncthreads()` give us built-in coordination/synchronization capability.)  This may have some challenges around data boundaries (e.g. inter-threadblock boundaries).  One approach to handling the border data is to have adjacent threadblocks perform redundant calculations in the border region, so that each threadblock is guaranteed to produce all necessary intermediate results before any final results are computed.  In this case, you can safely separate the computation of intermediate results with final results using `__syncthreads()`, which is an intra-threadblock [barrier](http://docs.nvidia.com/cuda/cuda-c-programming-guide/index.html#synchronization-functions).
3. In some cases, you can reduce the dependency to a single thread.  For example, in your code, you can make a single thread perform the necessary computation:

   ```
   initial_array[index+1] = powf(C[index+1],2);
   ```

   *and* the dependent result computation:

   ```
   result_array[index] = initial_array[index+1] / B[index];
   ```

   Since the dependent calculation is guaranteed to be performed after the necessary intermediate results are computed, there is no other synchronization needed. Probably your actual code may not lend itself to such a trivial rewrite.

As an aside, note that your use of `index+1` will go out of range for the last threadblock in the kernel (w = width -1, h = height-1).  Also, I don't think this indexing is what you intended:

```
        if (abs((result[i*(width-1)+j] - 50)) > 0.001){
```

I think you probably meant this:

```
        if (abs((result[i*(width)+j] - 50)) > 0.001){
```

With those changes, your `cuda_arithmetic` kernel runs correctly for me (even though it has a slight out-of-bounds issue.)

Answer (score -1):

Use `__syncthreads();`. All the code before `__syncthreads` will be executed in all threads launched by this kernel before any code after it is executed.

Also keep in mind that it's a good idea to separate read and write operations to avoid conflicts (when multiple threads read and write from the same addresses). For example

```
array[i] = array2[i]
```

should be reworked as

```
   temp = array2[i]; 
   __syncthreads();
   array[i] = temp;
   __syncthreads();
```

Comment: "All the code before `__syncthreads` will be executed in all threads launched by this kernel before any code after it is executed. "  This is not true.  `__syncthreads()` is a barrier for the threads within a single threadblock *only*, not the entire kernel.  `__syncthreads()` by itself in this case would not resolve the problem around threadblock boundaries.